# Trouble requiring a module in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, module

I am a beginner to the entire ReactJS ecosystem, and I am trying to build an app in React. I am using the create-react-app tool to create my app. Here is the relevant code to this problem:

App.js:

```
const findWord = require('../word'); //This is where I require the file

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.props = {
    }
  }
  getWord(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let word = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.wordInput).value;
    alert(word);
    findWord();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search">
        <form className="pure-form">
          <input ref="wordInput" type="text" placeholder="Search . . ."></input>
          <button onClick={this.getWord.bind(this)} className="pure-button pure-button-primary" type="button">Go</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

word.js:

```
var scraperjs = require('scraperjs'); //This is where I require the dependency

/* If I take the function out of the module.exports, then run the file with `node src/word.js`, it will work fine, but when I use it in the context of the application, then things go awry. */

module.exports = function(){
  scraperjs.StaticScraper.create('https://news.ycombinator.com/')
      .scrape(function($) {
          return $(".title a").map(function() {
              return $(this).text();
          }).get();
      })
      .then(function(news) {
          console.log(news);
      })
};
```

My trouble is that when I try to require the module(scraperjs) from a component class and use it, it generates an error in some random dependency.

```
Error in ./~/win-spawn/index.js
Module not found: 'child_process' in /Users/marknifakos/Documents/new-react-app/word-map-shs/node_modules/win-spawn

 @ ./~/win-spawn/index.js 1:13-37
```

When I use this module in with the plain node cli command, it works just fine, so the problem probably doesn't lie with the dependency itself. And I am 100% sure that the paths are correct, so don't bring that up either.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `child-process` module is an inbuilt module in Node, and not accessible by the browser. This also why you are able to access it using the cli, but not in the browser because webpack does not bundle it. Your best bet is to include the following in your webpack config:

```
node:
{
    "child_process": "empty"
}
```

And hope that your dependency does not need to use any methods from this module.

Comment: I am still getting the same errors. Sorry if I'm not providing enough info.

Comment: could you upload your work to github or someplace else where I can see it?